# UILocalNotification Custom soundName

Tags: uilocalnotification

How to custom uilocalnotification's sound? if the sound didn't located under main bundle.

/var/mobile/Applications/7B5E1007-CC44-42B9-A26D-3B6618BF434C/Documents/2011.06.10 12:38:13.caf this is sound address. i can play it by using AVAudio, how can i set to uilocalnotification?

By the way, i want to approve this  can be done. you can search the APP which name is RecordAlarm, made by Task Inc, it has free version. i check the caf address, it indeedly located at document, and can be used as alarm sound.

I am so confused about how they can do that?

BR, Ben
+8615828214917

Comment: Please don't mention your contact details here!

Answer (score 1):

You can only use sounds that are a part of the main bundle, meaning, they have be in the build of the app when submitted to the app store.

Yes, you can record sound, download sound, etc in app, but none of those sounds files created/saved can be used, because they are not in the app's bundle.  If an app is using custom sounds by accessing them outside of the bundle, then they are using private APIs to do so. Trust me, I've tried every option I can think of.

Comment: Welcome @Ben. Hope it saved you some headache.